# Finding an inverse of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\to R_3[x]$ be a linear transformation, where V is the vector space of the symmetric 2x2 matrices.
\begin{equation*}T(\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\b & c\end{pmatrix}) = (a+b+c)+(-a+2c)x+(2a+3b+6c)x^2\end{equation*}

Find the inverse of the linear transformation.

I have tried to find a matrix A so that T = Av, and then find the inverse of the matrix A.

I got to this inverse matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}1 & -4 & 2\\10& 4 & -3 \\-3 & -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}

So that \begin{equation*}T^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -4 & 2\\10& 4 & -3 \\-3 & -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}v\end{equation*}

But it doesn't make sense to me, since the inverse transformation $T^{-1}:R_3[x]\to$V
I mean, how can the inverted matrix I got, create a vector of the space of 2x2 matrices?

What am I missing?

Comment: The first two lines are unclear. You say that $V$ is a space of 2×2 matrices but you apply $T$ onto an asymetric 3×3 matrix. And then you have there letters $a,b,c$ but you don't explain what they are.

Comment: @Hume2 My bad, fixed

Comment: To find a matrix representing a linear transformation, first you have to select a basis for domain and a basis for codomain. Then you can represent each element of each vector space as an $n$-tuple (in this question, a triple of numbers), and multiplication by a matrix then makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

You use the same trick as when you were constructing the matrix just backwards.
$$
T^{-1}(p+qx+rx^2) = \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    b & c
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
where 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    a\\
    b\\
    c
    \end{pmatrix} = A^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}p\\q\\r\end{pmatrix}
$$
And better recalculate your inverse matrix, it doesn't seem to be right. It would help if you wrote there what matrix you tried to invert.